# Determinant when one of the diagonal entries of a triangular matrix is 0

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

To derive the determinant of a square matrix, we can always use elimination to convert it into an upper triangular matrix. For example, in the $M_{2 \times 2}$ case, we can always use elimination to convert the $M_{2 \times 2}$ to an upper triangular matrix. There are two cases to consider: when $a \neq 0$ and when $a=0$.

I understand the case where $a \neq 0$.

If $a \neq 0$, then

$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d-\frac{c}{a}b\end{bmatrix}$

We can then multiply the pivots along the diagonal line (i.e. $a \dot (d-\frac{c}{a}b) = ad - bc$)

But I am not sure the case when $a = 0$ (or one of the diagonal entries is $0$). Do I need to exchange rows? What properties of determinant do I need to use? I know the determinant is $0$ when the matrix is singular.

Edit: I am so sorry if the comment causes any confusion. It was due to a typo in the title. Initially, the title was: Determinant when one of the diagonal entries of a diagonal matrix is $0$. But, I actually meant to ask for the **Determinant of a triangular matrix when one of its diagonal entries is $0$**. This means that the counterexample $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ no longer works. The second last comment clears my concern :)

Comment: If $a=0$, then
$det\begin{pmatrix}
0 & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}=-det\begin{pmatrix}
c & d \\
0 & b 
\end{pmatrix}=-bc$, this is because the determinant is an **alternating** multilinear form.

Comment: Additionally take $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$, one of the diagonal entries is $0$, but the determinant is not $0$.

Comment: Yes, I know if you exchange two rows, the determinant reverses sign. This is also what I got. But I thought the determinant is 0. Because if one of the diagonal entries is 0, after elimination, we should get a row of zero right? Then, if a row is 0, then determinant is 0. I am not sure how this is possible to show in the case of a 2x2 matrix. It seems like after we exchange the two rows, we get $-bc$ as the determinant.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding something...

Comment: I gave you an counterexample to your believe, thats what I wrote in the fist comment.

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar Ok, I see. Thank you!

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar Sorry, I just realized that I meant a triangular matrix. The title of the question should be: determinant of a triangular matrix when one of its diagonal entries is 0. This completely changes the idea.

Comment: Now I have fixed the title of the question. I think if it is a triangular matrix and one of its diagonal entries is 0, then the determinant has to be 0 right? Because if I perform elimination, then there will be a row with all zeros. This means that the determinant is 0.

Comment: Yes, please note the edit of title in post, so the comments won't confuse anyone.

Comment: In this case, for example if we have an upper triangular $2x2$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & d  \end{pmatrix}$, then if $a=0$ by previous calculations $det\begin{pmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & d  \end{pmatrix}=-b(0)=0$. Of course this is true for any triangular $n\times n$ matrix with $0$'s on its diagonal.

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar I do see that. But, my thinking process was that: 1. we start with any general 2 by 2 matrix where the first diagonal entry $ a = 0 $ (i.e. $ \begin{bmatrix}0&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} $). 2. we use elimination to turn it into an upper triangular matrix by exchanging row 1 and row 2 (i.e. $ \begin{bmatrix}c&d\\0&b\end{bmatrix} $). 3. Now this has become an upper triangular matrix, and by the formula, the determinant should be $-bc$. This is not $0$. I am still confused...

Comment: It is if $b=0$ or $c=0$, which would mean one of the diagonal entries of the triangular matrix is $0$. The fact that you take a matrix with a zero entry and transform it into a triangular matrix, does not lead to the matrix dererminant being zero.

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar Ok, I see. Thank you very much!